# Adsorption calcs using Quantum ESPRESSO

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, surfaces

I already built a copper surface using BURAI and I used an SCF calculation to find the total energy of this surface. Now, what is the next step to finding the adsorption energy of one H2 molecule on this surface?

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! We hope to see much more of you in the future!!! Thank you for contributing your question here.

Comment: Take a look at the discussion [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/378/24).

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1**

Calculate energy of copper slab with hydrogen molecule on slab: $E(Cu+H_2) $

**Step 2**

Calculate energy of copper slab: $E(Cu) $

**Step 3**

Calculate energy of hydrogen molecule: $E(H_2) $

$E^{ad}(H_2)$ = $E(Cu+H_2)$ -
$E(Cu)$-$E(H_2)$

Hydrogen adsoption on copper surface will vary with different binding sites such as hollow/Bridge site and with different crystallography orientation (For example $E(100)\neq E(110)$).

Comment: Sir, thank you so much. Let me know if I understood. After I know the total energy for surface copper using the SCF calculation, do I need to make the same procedure for H2 molecule? I mean, do I need to know the total energy for H2 using the SCF calculate

Comment: Yes, you need three calculation 1) copper surface with H2 2) copper surface without H2 and 3) H2 only .  You need to perform atomic relaxation, as well as surface atoms, will move.  For the hydrogen molecule, create a large box (10 Ang), put the H2 molecule, and calculate minimum energy of that molecule (allow atoms to move).

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Sir, where can I find files for H2 molecules
For solids, I am using AMCSD and put in BURAI, but where can I find molecules files?

Comment: Use a separate question in forum